# Crystal report fields are blank even after I run a query... Query is from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, report

What i wanna do is to show data of two tables in a single Crystal Report file or page. It brings the fields, but when i run the query it doesn't show any data in report.
FYI, i have used the same query to bring data from sql server to fill a GridView and it has worked.

```
        private void employee_report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        DAL d = new DAL();        // It is a separte C# class in which i have created connection
        d.connect();

        d.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT employee.emp_id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name, employee.gender, employee.dob, employee.city, employee.province, employee.phone_number, employee.email, employee.designation, department.department_name FROM department, employee WHERE employee.department_id = department.department_id AND is_deleted = 0";
        d.cmd.Connection = d.con;

        d.da.SelectCommand = d.cmd;
        d.da.Fill(d.dt);

        d.disconnect();

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.FileName = "emp_report.rpt";
        rd.SetDataSource(d.dt);

        report_employee.ReportSource = rd;
        report_employee.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: King Wardak.. What you "wanna" do is upto you. However, have you added the two tables to the report and joined them appropriately?

Comment: @aMazing check my Query... that query works perfectly well when i run it in SQL Server but it doesn't work in CrystalReports... The tables have a foreign key constraint which the CrystalReport wizard selected by itself. Now i don't know really what to do..

Comment: How are you designing your crystal report?

Comment: @aMazing I didn't understand ur question

Comment: I mean, how are you doing your crystal report? Are you adding tables using the Database Expert? or some other way?